# Vue. js CORS issues, backend data blocked by CORS policy

Tags: vue.js, cors

I am using Vuejs with CLI 3.6.3 and i am facing CORS issue so i can not get the backend api data.

The error message is :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://...' 
from origin 'http://localhost:8080' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I do create a vue.config.js file :

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      proxy: 'https://my/site/myapi/myindex.php',
  }
}
```

import axios and declare crossDomain equals true:

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.crossDomain = true;
```

And at the backend i do declare:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
```

How can i access the backend api data without facing CORS issues ?

Comment: Not sure what your backend code is, such as node.js or php but there could be a package that  could resolve this issue. Also you can try proxying your requests with  another server like `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Assuming your backend is in PHP (and those header() calls are PHP and are actually running), everything looks good. Without seeing the rest of your backend code this will be hard to debug. Make sure your header() calls happen *before* anything is echo'ed, or the headers won't be set.

Comment: I would check the networks tab of your browser to make sure those cors headers are coming through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```

This is should be there where is api is accepting the request

Comment: Worked for me. header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); did not solve it but when I tried this it worked.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With');
```

At the construct method of the backend it start to work.